# Values getting mixed up in NSURL request async

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm conducting an NSURL request asynchronously. It works fine for the most part, but sometimes it returns a `200 OK` for hosts which are obviously bogus. Here's the code for the connection:

```
-(void)checkConnectionForHost:(NSString*)host completion:(completion_t)completionHandler
{
   NSURLRequest* request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:host]];
   if([NSURLConnection canHandleRequest:request]){
      [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
         if(completionHandler)
         {
            completionHandler(connectionError == nil && [(NSHTTPURLResponse*)response statusCode]==200);
         }
      }];
   }

}
```

And the completion handler:

```
typedef void (^completion_t)(BOOL isReachable);
```

I'm calling this command for each cell in my data source in the `collectionView:cellForItem...` delegate method.

The reason I know this isn't working is because I sent in some random host like `8107341897309` and it immediately returned a `0` status, but then changed to `200`. Also, if I send in a value with a string, it stays `0`. When I send in a value with just integers or decimals, this keeps jumping around. Any insight would be great!

EDIT: So sometimes when it connects it returns a `0` and other times it returns a `200`. What I was trying to say is that results are inconsistent.

EDIT 2: Decided to log the results I got in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath` and got this:

```
    2014-01-04 19:22:53.390 ServerObserver[5624:4703] http://192.168.1.11 is Reachable? : 1. Index: 0
2014-01-04 19:22:53.414 ServerObserver[5624:3707] http://apple.com is Reachable? : 1. Index: 6
2014-01-04 19:22:53.619 ServerObserver[5624:4003] http://192.168.1.11 is Reachable? : 1. Index: 0
2014-01-04 19:22:53.697 ServerObserver[5624:5603] http://google.com is Reachable? : 1. Index: 1
2014-01-04 19:22:53.696 ServerObserver[5624:4003] http://pandora.com is Reachable? : 1. Index: 5
2014-01-04 19:22:53.705 ServerObserver[5624:4003] http://apple.com is Reachable? : 1. Index: 6
2014-01-04 19:22:53.732 ServerObserver[5624:5603] http://reddit.com is Reachable? : 1. Index: 4
2014-01-04 19:22:53.781 ServerObserver[5624:1803] http://google.com is Reachable? : 1. Index: 1
2014-01-04 19:22:53.893 ServerObserver[5624:5603] http://twitter.com is Reachable? : 1. Index: 3
2014-01-04 19:22:53.896 ServerObserver[5624:5603] http://reddit.com is Reachable? : 1. Index: 4
2014-01-04 19:22:53.891 ServerObserver[5624:1803] http://pandora.com is Reachable? : 1. Index: 5
2014-01-04 19:22:54.038 ServerObserver[5624:4003] http://twitter.com is Reachable? : 1. Index: 3
2014-01-04 19:22:54.268 ServerObserver[5624:5603] http://facebook.com is Reachable? : 1. Index: 2
2014-01-04 19:22:54.317 ServerObserver[5624:5603] http://facebook.com is Reachable? : 1. Index: 2
```

Some things to note are that the junk IP doesn't even show up here, because I check in the previous method, if the request "can be made". But, why is each IP being called twice? Each cell only has a single IP.

Comment: Care to explain: "immediately returned a 0 status, but then changed to 200"?

Comment: Use a network analyzer like Charles Proxy to see exactly what is being send and received.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've updated the OP

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1094

Comment: @AaronBrager thanks for the link. It seems that they concluded that the server the person was testing was at fault. I'm pretty sure that the host I created while mashing my keyboard isn't a real one haha :)

Comment: Oops I've seen it used interchangeably with "original post"

Comment: When it's returning a zero, what is `response` (I bet it's `nil`) and what is `connectionError` (I bet it's reporting the connection error)? And when it's `200`, what is the `data` (I bet if you look at it, converting it to a string, that it might be an HTML page generated by your ISP that says "oh, I couldn't find that web site, did you mean X?".) My ISP (Verizon FiOS) has this incredibly annoying feature (including the inconsistency of the behavior).

Comment: @Rob when it's returning 0 it is 0 and it works fine. Error is always `(null)`, because if you look at my edit, it's now only testing valid URLs. And thankfully, my ISP (Comcast) doesn't do that haha

Comment: @Rob Will do. And also: I read somewhere that `NSURLConnection` has to be closed? How can I do that? I tried instantiating `NSURLConnection`, but it didn't let me access other methods such as `send...`,etc.

Comment: Okay, I've updated to add the index. I'm assuming the indexes are scattered because the async returns at different times? Also, I do use `reloadData` when -`viewWillAppear:` and when a button is pressed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44537/discussion-between-rob-and-carpetfizz)

Comment: Please show the code where you update the cell's value. Additionally, a GET request is likely not the best method to check for reachability. You may try a HEAD request instead. But you are better off using the system's reachability functions, see `SCNetworkReachability` in the Apple Docs.

Comment: You just want to know if the URL's exist on web?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use check if url exists like this:

```
- (BOOL)urlExistsOnServer:(NSString *)strURL
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"HEAD"];
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]];
    NSMutableArray *json = (NSMutableArray*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSString *retVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // you can use retVal , ignore if you don't need.
    NSInteger httpStatus = [((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response) statusCode];
    NSLog(@"responsecode:%d retVal:%@\njson:%@", httpStatus,retVal,json);

    if(httpStatus != 200)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

If you need to check URL's Asynchronously you will need to refine this code, but this worked for me.

Comment: There is no advantage using this code over the OPs one, except a HEAD may be better. However, this approach won't work reliable: for example, if the server requires authentication it may respond with a different status code than 200 (OK) - yet it is actually "reachable". (see SCNetworkReachability for testing reachability)

Comment: Thanks, in my app the server is known and I am checking if a file exists by adding to the URL the name of the file. So in my case this code works great(;